# Simple button looks Ok in Blend, not in app

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a simple button described like this:

```
<Button x:Name="btn_Close" Width="35" Height="35" Click="CloseButton_Click" Margin="1152.332,17,13.667,840">
    <Button.Template>
        <ControlTemplate>
            <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1">
                <Image Source="closewindow.png" Margin="5"/>
            </Border>                   
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Button.Template>
</Button>
```

It renders like this in Blend:

[image: Close button in Blend]

But when I same the XAML file and compile and run the app it belongs to in VS2013, it looks like this in the app.

[image: Close button in app]

What happened? Where am I going wrong with such a simple thing?

Comment: Remove margin property of the button

Comment: That did work, but now it is not located where I wanted it. How do I put it where I want it with out a margin property?

Comment: You should not position you control based on margin property. You should place all your controls in a proper container like Stackpanel or Grid. So Share your XAML and tell me where do you want to put the button.

Comment: Ok, I get that...  I wan't aware that margins used outside of proper containers had such odd side-effects.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the **VerticalAlignment** and **HorizontalAlignment** for Button.
You can locate your Button via margin property.

Take an instance

```
<Button VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" x:Name="btn_Close" Width="35" Height="35" Margin="1152.332,17">
```